How can I refactor from error to an ExceptT?
I'm trying to refactor a piece of code to use a monad.
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
data Order = LeftToRight | RightToLeft
  deriving Show

ordering :: [String] -> Map String Order
ordering ls = Map.fromList pairs -- TODO: refactor to a monad
  where
  pairs = map parseOrder ls
  parseOrder s =
    case words s of
      [v, o] -> (v, o')
        where
          o' = case o of
            "l2r" -> LeftToRight
            "r2l" -> RightToLeft
            _     -> error $ "parse error in ordering:" ++ s
      _ -> error $ "parse error in ordering: " ++ s

I am trying to wrap the errors inside of an ExceptT, but I can't figure out how to yank out the code from the where clause into the right lifted format. Here is what I've tried:
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map

import qualified System.Exit as Exit
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)

die :: String -> ExceptT () IO a
die msg = liftIO $ Exit.die ("\ESC[31mERROR: \ESC[0m" ++ msg)

data Order = LeftToRight | RightToLeft
  deriving Show

ordering' :: [String] -> ExceptT () IO (Map String Order)
ordering' ls = return (Map.fromList pairs)
  where
  pairs = map parseOrder ls
  parseOrder s =
    case words s of
      [v, o] -> (v, o')
        where
          o' = case o of
            "l2r" -> LeftToRight
            "r2l" -> RightToLeft
            _     -> die $ "parse error in ordering:" ++ s
      _ -> die $ "parse error in ordering: " ++ s


main :: IO ()
main = do
  let x = ["a l2r", "b r2l", "b c r2l"]
  p <- runExceptT $ ordering' x
  putStrLn (show p)

This gives the error
eg.hs:30:37: error: [GHC-83865]
    • Couldn't match type ‘ExceptT () IO Order’ with ‘Order’
      Expected: [(String, Order)]
        Actual: [(String, ExceptT () IO Order)]
    • In the first argument of ‘Map.fromList’, namely ‘pairs’
      In the first argument of ‘return’, namely ‘(Map.fromList pairs)’
      In the expression: return (Map.fromList pairs)
   |
30 | ordering' ls = return (Map.fromList pairs)
   |                                     ^^^^^

What is going on here? Isn't it the case that return wraps the Map String Order in the monad of the correct type, or do I need to lift something?
If possible, I would prefer to keep a similar structure of the where definitions, since this coding pattern is used many different places in the code base I'm working with.

You have to sequence the pairs list to get the monad one level higher, and similar for the tuple.

I find the ExceptT () (IO a) a bit odd, you don't do any IO in ordering', and the ExceptT is exactly used to handle an exception, not to print it directly (i.e. die).

Just as you've defined your own Order type, consider defining something like data ParseError = ParseError String. Then you can just return ParseError s, and let whoever handles that value decide if they want to bother rendering it with a message like "parse error in ordering: " ++ s.

This is essentially cafce25's solution. You need to "sequence" out both the list and the tuple. Since a tuple isn't Traversable, you have to write your own function.
import Control.Monad (liftM2)

ordering' :: [String] -> ExceptT () IO (Map String Order)
ordering' ls = pairs >>= (\p -> return (Map.fromList p))
  where
  pairs = sequence $ map parseOrder ls
  parseOrder s = do
    case words s of
      [v, o] -> ts2 (return v, o')
        where
          ts2 = uncurry $ liftM2 (,)
          o' = case o of
            "l2r" -> return LeftToRight
            "r2l" -> return RightToLeft
            _     -> die $ "parse error in ordering:" ++ s
      _ -> die $ "parse error in ordering: " ++ s


ts2 (return v, o') is equivalent to (v, ) <$> o'

I find the ExceptT () (IO a) a bit odd, you don't do any IO in ordering', and the ExceptT is exactly used to handle an exception, not to print it directly (i.e. die).
Typically you see an ExceptT to "catch" an exception, and then handle it accordingly, so for example then die outside the ordering' block:
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}

ordering' :: [String] -> Except String (Map String Order)
ordering' ls = Map.fromList <$> sequence pairs
  where
    pairs = map parseOrder ls
    parseOrder s =
      case words s of
        [v, o] -> (v,) <$> o'
          where
            o' = case o of
              "l2r" -> pure LeftToRight
              "r2l" -> pure RightToLeft
              _ -> throwE $ "parse error in ordering:" ++ s
        _ -> throwE $ "parse error in ordering: " ++ s
Then you can inspect if an exception has been raised by ordering' and thus let the process die accordingly.
(This next bit contains style suggestions only, and is somewhat subjective.) You might like to compact some of these steps: sequence (map parseOrder ls) = mapM parseOrder ls, and the inner case can be lifted up a level to avoid having to repeat the error reporting.
ordering' :: [String] -> Except String (Map String Order)
ordering' ls = Map.fromList <$> mapM parseOrder ls
  where
    parseOrder s =
      case words s of
        [v, "l2r"] -> pure (v, LeftToRight)
        [v, "r2l"] -> pure (v, RightToLeft)
        _ -> throwE $ "parse error in ordering: " ++ s


I wonder if "you don't do any IO" really ought to be "you shouldn't do any IO". After all, in the original code snippet, the actual fact is that there is liftIO but no throwE -- that is, they actually do only IO and no ExceptT stuff.

I am doing IO in ordering, it is just via the magic function error. That is why I wanted to refactor it. The issue with the ordering' that you wrote is I would still have to handle the exception in the caller. Instead, I would like to handle them directly in the ordering - I use this as an example because this pattern shows up in many different places where the data structure I am using is an instance of ExceptT.

@sdpoll: but that does not make nuch sense: if you want to raise an exception, you can just use die "..." in the IO. ExceptT is exactly meant to give control to the caller, as some sort of try-except pattern. So then ExceptT is essentially useless. But here IO is probably not useful, since we don't do any IO in the thing, and thus only "restricting" the use of ordering'.

Thanks for the clarification. You are right, the reason I used Except was to more closely match the code I'm working with but it is not necessary to do both Exception handling and IO. My challenge is that Monad transformers are hard to grok

@sdpoll: well I don't think a transformer is very useful in this case. These are very powerful to "stack" multiple monadic things on top of each other (although typically if the number of layers is large, these often start being more a pain than a gain), but usually only if there are two monadic things from wich you need something. Here it does not look like you need IO, or perhaps not need ExceptT, but at least not the two combined.
